# Checking for boolean in Java switch case

Tags: java, numbers, switch-statement, contains

So I have a switch case into switch I am inputting a string and my cases are .contains as shown in my code below:

```
    intcheck: switch(line){
    case line.contains("0"):
    case line.contains("1"):
    case line.contains("2"):
    case line.contains("3"):
    case line.contains("4"):
    case line.contains("5"):
    case line.contains("6"):
    case line.contains("7"):
    case line.contains("8"):
    case line.contains("9"):
      break intcheck;
    default:
      names.put(br.readline(),0);
  }
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar to this using a switch statement or will I have to use
if statements. Also is there an easier way to check if a string contains a digit or is that OK?

Comment: That is not possible. How about `if (!line.replaceAll("\\D+", "").isEmpty())` (create a new string replacing all of the non-digits in `line` with `""` check if that is not empty - only true when the `line` has at least one digit).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why not just `line.matches(".*\\d.*")` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Looks good to me. I went with the first thing that occurred and seemed reasonable for the problem.

Comment: If you switch on a `boolean` you can only have two cases: `true` and `false`; and the case values must be constants, not (non-final) variables or method return values.

Comment: It is not possible because you are passing `String` as `switch` parameter and mapping with `boolean` in `case` statement.

for you have to use `if..else ladder` or similar logic. Otherwise you have to use same datatype in `switch case` for parameter and for mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it could be done better in a different way, if you insist in a `switch-case` construct, try this:

```
OptionalInt containedNumber = OptionalInt.empty();
Intcheck: for( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
  switch( i )
  {
    case 0: if( line.contains( "0" ) containedNumber = OptionalInt.of( 0 ); break Intcheck;
    case 1: if( line.contains( "1" ) containedNumber = OptionalInt.of( 1 ); break Intcheck;
    …
    case 9: if( line.contains( "9" ) containedNumber = OptionalInt.of( 9 ); break Intcheck;
    default:
      continue IntCheck;
  }
}
if( containedNumber.isEmpty() ) names.put( br.readline(), 0 )
```

Without the `switch-case`:

```
OptionalInt containedNumber = OptionalInt.empty();
for( var i = 0; (i < 10) && containedNumber.isEmpty(); ++i )
{
    if( line.contains( Integer.toString( i ) ) containedNumber = OptionalInt.of( i );
}
if( containedNumber.isEmpty() ) names.put( br.readline(), 0 )
```